# How to get specific value of the object?

Tags: javascript

I wrote:

```
function myObj() {

    return 7;

}

console.log(new myObj());
```

It returns:

```
 myObj {}
```

Why is this happens?

How to make `new myObj()` to return me: `7`?

I am interesting in specification of `new myObj()` without calling of additional properties?

**this task:**

```
new myObj() // return 1;
new myObj() // return 2;

new myObj() + new myObj() = // return 7;
```

Comment: `new` is for creating objects. If you don't want an object, just call `myObj()` instead of `new myObj()`.

Comment: 1 + 2 = 7 ?? :))))))

Comment: no, this counter: new myObj() // 1; new myObj() // 2 and ...;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new myObj` creates and returns a new object, even though you have `return 7` in your function. The `new` operator is specifically for creating objects, and has the interesting behavior of completely ignoring the return value of the constructor function *unless* it's a non-`null` object reference; instead, `new` returns the object it created. (If you *do* return a non-`null` object reference from the constructor function, it overrides `new`'s default behavior; use cases for this are rare.)

If you just want to call the function and get its return value, don't use `new`:

```
console.log(myObj());
```

If you want to create an object with a property on it, and set that property to `7`, then print it, you need to create the property:

```
function myObj() {
    this.thePropertyName = 7;
}
```

...and then use it:

```
var o = new myObj();
console.log(o.thePropertyName);
```

...or:

```
console.log(new myObj().thePropertyName);
```

...but then you're creating and releasing an object for no good reason.

---

Re your edit, which changes the question ***markedly***:

> this task:
>
> ```
> new myObj() // return 1; new myObj() // return 2;
>
> new myObj() + new myObj() = // return 7;
> ```

That's a bizarre requirement. It breaks down like this:

1. Every time you call `new myObj`, save a number (starting with `1`).
2. When the `+` operator is used on the objects, return that number.

You **can** do it, by using a common counter, a value on the instance, and overriding the default implementations of `toString` and `valueOf`; see comments in the code:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  // Use a scoping function to build `myObj` so that we
  // keep the counter private
  var myObj = (function() {
    // The counter
    var counter = 0;

    // The `myObj` function we'll return
    function myObj() {
      // Increment the counter, remember the number
      this.value = ++counter;
    }
    
    // When a coercion to number is preferred, JavaScript will
    // use the valueOf function
    myObj.prototype.valueOf = function() {
      return this.value;
    };
    
    // When a coercion to string is preferred, JavaScript will
    // use the toString function
    myObj.prototype.toString = function() {
      return String(this.value);
    };

    // Return `myObj` from our scoping function to export it
    return myObj;
  })();

  // Using it
  display(new myObj());               // "1"
  display(new myObj());               // "2"
  display(new myObj() + new myObj()); // 7

  // Utility function
  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

Comment: this task! needed to: new myObj() + new myObj() = 3

Comment: @Nepster Why don't you accept this answer instead of complaining as it is the most complete and he went above and beyond explaining Object properties.

Comment: @Nepster: Your edit **significantly** changes the question (and makes it a bit bizarre). I've updated the answer to answer the new question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This task was at interview of my friend.
it was his decision http://jsfiddle.net/z6yoLx6b/1/.
I was confused by console.log. I've tried to get the number at console.log. Thank you. I go read about JavaScript.

Comment: @Nepster: Your friend's solution relies on the fact that returning a non-`null` object (`new Number(myObj.count)`) overrides `new`'s default behavior, and that the `valueOf` and `toString` of `Number` objects returns the number. Note that `new` is completely unnecessary: http://jsfiddle.net/z6yoLx6b/2/ And in fact, re your friend's solution, if we get rid of `new` we can get rid of `new Number`: http://jsfiddle.net/z6yoLx6b/3/ (And you don't need `String()` on what you pass to `alert` in any case, it converts to string implicitly.)

Comment: string, - I checked the result in the console.log =)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript , a function is also a class. Calling the function like myObj() will return the value 7.
But calling with new will crete an instance of that object and return the object,and so 7 will not be returned.

Comment: this task! needed to: new myObj() + new myObj() = 3